# Is this a female date palm?

Tags: palm

[image: Date Palm]

I think it is but not certain.

Comment: I removed the part of your question about where to buy as that is not a good fit for here and otherwise this question would be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a female date palm inflorescence. The male flowers are tightly clustered.  Here is a picture of a female inflorescence from Wikipedia

[image: female date palm inflorescence]

and here is a male flower from [medjool-date-palms.com](https://www.medjool-date-palms.com/html/male-date-palm-flower-pollen.html#purchase-date-palm-pollen-flowers) which offers information on growing date palms in California

[image: male date palm flower]